# How does the endorsing peer will check or confirm if submitting client signature is valid

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Would you please help me to understand the below questions. These questions are internals of fabric architecture and have not been very well documented in the fabric docs.

1. Whenever an identity is issued to an user it could be either type of peer, orderer, admin and client. How does the endorsing peer will check or confirm if submitting client signature is valid [Assuming client signed the proposal using private key and the endorsing peer will have the client public key to verify, but still the integrity is not assured]
2. How does each endorsing peer ensures that the transaction submitter satisfies the channel’s Writers policy. Submitter here is client who has rights to submit a transaction proposal.

The genesis block does not contains application client certificates and they can be generated and issued in later stage also. So that means Endorsing peer would have a mechanism to understand a valid certificate issued by CA who is also part of the network whom it can trust. I am not able to these intrinsic mechanism created and implemented in fabric.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a component called msp(membership service provider) which stores the keys and certs used in the blockchain network. It is present on all participating nodes. Take a look at this https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/msp.html.

Comment: User related MSP's are not present in participating nodes. What you are referring is about peer node identity. my question is more about client identity. See the point 1 & 2 .

Answer (score 0):

1. Endorsing peer is having the root certificate of the organization's CA. Peers receive them when their organisation joins the channel using genesis block. The transaction proposal has the client's signature and it's X.509 certificate. Endorser can verify if client's identity (X.509 certificate) is coming from the organisation's CA using the root certificate of the CA.
2. Channel policy and the root CA certificates are available inside genesis block. Genesis block is generated using the channel configuration file(configtx.yaml). This genesis block is used at the time of joining channel.

Comment: Thanks . I have a doubt For ex: If there are three organizations each having their own CA, So every peer from different organization when joining in to a channel gets all the three root certificate of organization's CA ?